Diagonal box in a table
I'd like to have a proper diagonal line in the top left cell - going from the top left corner to the right end corner. Moreover, the vertical lines in the main body of the table are not consistent, and I do not see how to fix that.
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\textwidth= 5.00in
\textheight= 7.4in
\topmargin = 30pt
\evensidemargin=0pt
\oddsidemargin=55pt
\headsep=17pt
\parskip=.8pt
\parindent=12pt
\font\smallit=cmti10
\font\smalltt=cmtt10
\font\smallrm=cmr9

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath} 
\usepackage{diagbox}

\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{||c|c|c|c|c||}
\hline
\backslashbox{1st scenario}{2nd scenario}& $(aaaaaaa,$ & $(aaaaaaa,$ & $(aaaaaaa,$ & $(aaaaaaa,$ \\ [0.5ex]
& $bbbbbbb)$ & $bbbbbbbb)$ & $bbbbbbbb)$ & $bbbbbbbb)$ \\ [0.5ex]
\hline\hline \\[0.15ex]
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & $ddddddd^1$ & $ddddddd^2$ & $ddddddd^3$ & $ddddddd^4$\\ 
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & $ddddddd^1$ & $ddddddd^2$ & $ddddddd^3$ & $ddddddd^4$\\  [1ex] 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 
\end{document}



Unrelated, you should remove the useless \makeatletter.

Your diagonal line is proper aligned. It seems that you may like that it should gov over two rows ...  Is this a ca case what you after?

With nicematrix you can use the \diagbox command in a \Block:

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\textwidth= 5.00in
\textheight= 7.4in
\topmargin = 30pt
\evensidemargin=0pt
\oddsidemargin=55pt
\headsep=17pt
\parskip=.8pt
\parindent=12pt
\font\smallit=cmti10
\font\smalltt=cmtt10
\font\smallrm=cmr9

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath} 
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\scriptsize
\begin{NiceTabular}{||c|c|c|c|c||}
\hline
\Block{2-1}{\diagbox{1st scenario}{2nd scenario}}& $(aaaaaaa,$ & $(aaaaaaa,$ & $(aaaaaaa,$ & $(aaaaaaa,$ \\[0.5ex]
& $bbbbbbb)$ & $bbbbbbbb)$ & $bbbbbbbb)$ & $bbbbbbbb)$ \\[0.5ex]
\hline\hline \\[0.15ex]
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & $ddddddd^1$ & $ddddddd^2$ & $ddddddd^3$ & $ddddddd^4$\\ 
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & $ddddddd^1$ & $ddddddd^2$ & $ddddddd^3$ & $ddddddd^4$\\[1ex] 
\hline 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center} 
\end{document}


You probably looks for something like this:

what is according to my opinion not the best looking table. Anyway, above table is produced by:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\parindent=12pt

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath} 
\usepackage{diagbox, 
            makecell} % <--- added

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{||c|c|c|c|c||}
    \hline
\backslashbox{\thead{1st scenario}}{\thead{2nd scenario}}
        & \thead{$(aaaaaaa,$\\ $bbbbbbb)$}   
            & \thead{$(aaaaaaa,$\\ $bbbbbbb)$}    
                & \thead{$(aaaaaaa,$\\ $bbbbbbb)$}  
                    & \thead{$(aaaaaaa,$\\ $bbbbbbb)$}  \\  
    \hline\hline 
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & $ddddddd^1$ & $ddddddd^2$ & $ddddddd^3$ & $ddddddd^4$\\ 
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & $ddddddd^1$ & $ddddddd^2$ & $ddddddd^3$ & $ddddddd^4$\\ 
    \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center} 
\end{document}

where contents of the first two rows are merged into one by use of  thead instruction defined in the makecell package.
However, to my opinion the following table is more professional appealing:

By use of tblr from tabularray package the MWE is simpler and shorter in comparison to the first one:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\parindent=12pt

\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
\scriptsize
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {*{5}{c}},
             cell{1}{1} ={r=2}{},
             cell{1}{2} ={c=4}{}
             }
    \toprule
1st scenario    &   2nd scenario
                    &   &   &                               \\
    \midrule
                &   {$(aaaaaaa,$\\ $bbbbbbb)$}   
                    &   {$(aaaaaaa,$\\ $bbbbbbb)$}    
                        &   {$(aaaaaaa,$\\ $bbbbbbb)$}  
                            &   {$(aaaaaaa,$\\ $bbbbbbb)$}  \\  
    \midrule
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & $ddddddd^1$ & $ddddddd^2$ & $ddddddd^3$ & $ddddddd^4$\\ 
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & $ddddddd^1$ & $ddddddd^2$ & $ddddddd^3$ & $ddddddd^4$\\  [1ex] 
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{center}
 
\end{document}


You need to merge the two rows in the first cell, and/or set the \diagbox height with something like
\diagbox[height=2\baselineskip]{1st scenario}{2nd scenario}

May I suggest something with the tabularray package?
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

  \begin{tblr}
    {
      colspec={||*{5}{Q[c,m]|}|},   % five columns, centered content
      hline{1}={1}{-}{},            % first hline
      hline{Z}={1}{-}{},            % last hline
      hline{2}={1}{-}{},            % double hline after the first row
      hline{2}={2}{-}{},
      cells={mode=math},            % all cells are in math mode
      column{1}={mode=text},        % except the first column
      row{1}={mode=text},           % and the first row (as multilined)
    }
    \diagbox[height=2\baselineskip]{1st scenario}{2nd scenario}
    & { ($aaaaaaa$, \\ $bbbbbbbb$) } % multilined cell
    & { ($aaaaaaa$, \\ $bbbbbbbb$) }
    & { ($aaaaaaa$, \\ $bbbbbbbb$) }
    & { ($aaaaaaa$, \\ $bbbbbbbb$) }
    \\[0.15ex]
    cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & ddddddd^1 & ddddddd^2 & ddddddd^3 & ddddddd^4\\
    cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc & ddddddd^1 & ddddddd^2 & ddddddd^3 & ddddddd^4
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}


